# How to extract one frame of a video every N seconds to an image?

Tags: video, images, ffmpeg, mplayer, capture

How can I convert a video file to a sequence of images, for example one frame every N seconds. Can mplayer or ffmpeg do this? I have used MPlayer to grab screenshots manually but I would like to automate this for a long video.

Comment: See this related question about choosing the quality of images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225403/how-can-i-extract-a-good-quality-jpeg-image-from-an-h264-video-file-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
mplayer -vo jpeg -sstep 5 file.avi
```

will save a frame as a jpeg file every 5 seconds.

However, it will not stop at the end of the file, it will continue producing copies of the last frame. To avoid this, find the duration of the video in seconds, using another player, or with mplayer:

```
mplayer -vo null -ao null -frames 0 -identify file.avi
```

and look for a line like "ID_LENGTH=147.00".

Subtract 2 from the length, and use this value for the `-endpos`option. For example, for a 147 second video:

```
mplayer -vo jpeg -sstep 5 -endpos 145 file.avi
```

Comment: this sounds like an mplayer bug.  nice workaround.

Comment: Could you at least mention on which operating system are you using this command?

Comment: It was 5 years ago, but it was probably the latest Ubuntu Desktop at the time, Ubuntu 10.4 .

Comment: How can I choose steps shorter than 1s. It does only accept integers.

Comment: Nowadays, `mpv --vo=image --sstep=5 movie.mkv` works great without the aforementioned bug ([mpv](http://mpv.io/) is a fork of mplayer) using mpv 0.27.0 on Debian.

Comment: I appreciate how on Super User this answer is 2nd even though it's the accepted answer.  On SO and SO Meta the accepted answer is showed first

Comment: if you use mpv, make sure to add --keep-open=no so the command finishes on completion (it may be the default or not, depending on your distro)

Answer (score 125):

It's very simple with ffmpeg, and it *can* output one frame every N seconds *without* extra scripting. To export as an image sequence just use `myimage_%04d.png` or similar as the output. The `%0xd` bit is converted to a zero-padded integer `x` digits long - the example I gave gets output as

- `myimage_0000.png`,
- `myimage_0001.png`,
- `myimage_0002.png`

  etc..

You can use lots of still image formats, png, jpeg, tga, whatever (see `ffmpeg -formats` for a full list).

**Ok so now we know how to export the movie as a sequence of images, but say we don't want to export every single frame?**

The trick is to simply change the frame rate of the output to whatever we want using the `-r n` option where `n` is the number of frames per second. 1 frame per second would be `-r 1`, one frame every four seconds would be `-r 0.25`, one frame every ten seconds would be `-r 0.1` and so on.

So to put it all together, this is how it would look to save one frame of `input.mov` every four seconds to `output_0000.png`, `output_0001.png` etc.:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 0.25 output_%04d.png
```

Note that the `-r 0.25` option goes *after* the `-i input.mov` part, because it's controlling the frame rate of the *output*. If you put it *before* the input it would treat the input file as if it had the specified frame rate.

Change the %xd to however many digits you need, e.g. if the command would create more than 10,000 frames change the `%04d` to `%05d`. This also works for input files that are image sequence. Read more [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence).

**Windows users**:
On the command line use `%`

example: `ffmpeg -i inputFile.mp4 -r 1 outputFile_%02d.png`

In CMD and BAT Scripts use `%%`

example: `ffmpeg -i inputFile.mp4 -r 1 outputFile %%02d.png`

So double `%%` in scripts, and single `%` on the interactive command line. Getting it wrong in either situation will generate an error.

**Edit** Worth checking out the discussion of file types in the comments below. There are advantages and disadvantages with each:

- jpeg *much* smaller file sizes, lossy, only 8-bit colour, no alpha.
- png lossless, large files, slow. 8-bit colour supports alpha.
- tiff lossless, even larger files, fast, supports up to 16 colour and alpha.

To specify the file format, just use the required extension in the output file, e.g. `myimage_%04d.jpg`, `myimage_%04d.png` or `myimage_%04d.tiff`

Comment: What should I put into `-r` if I want to export *every* frame? If I know the video's FPS, I guess I input that, but what if I don't?

Comment: Don't use the -r flag at all. Then FFMPEG will use the input file's frame rate.

Comment: Note that you'll **really** want to use `jpegs` for this, unless you're sure `png`'s are what you want. In my case, `jpeg`s were about 50kb each, and `png`s were about 2MB.

Comment: the advantage of pngs is lossless compression, so if you're using the image sequence as an intermediate and don't mind the extra size then that's when you might use png.

Comment: It is worth to add that `-q:v 1` is a very useful option here as in https://superuser.com/questions/318845/improve-quality-of-ffmpeg-created-jpgs

Comment: This should probably be its own question, but @stib is that why most of the images I find on Google are .jpgs?  Because they're smaller?

Comment: Not only its own question, but probably on a different site… But whatevs: to oversimplify, jpegs work better for photographs (or stills from video), where better means smaller file for less perceptible quality loss, pngs are lossless, and deal with text and design elements much better. See this definitive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-vs-svg-when-best-to-use

Comment: Tip: make sure the `-r 1` goes *AFTER* the input file, otherwise it doesn't have the intended effect.

Comment: @stib for `-r` > 1 how are those frames distributed? I'm trying to extract 5 frames from every second of video which are evenly distributed across that second.

Comment: @mlissner but with `jpeg`s also quality considerably drops in my case in contrast with `png`s

Comment: @FilipAllberg If r = 5 you'll get five frames at 1/5 second intervals.

Comment: Might be worth noting that TIFFs, while larger are much, much faster than pngs. This is important if you're using them as an image sequence.

Comment: I used this to create a time-lapse video. Simple to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

With [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/), you can do the following:

```
ffmpeg -ss 4 -i input.avi -s 320x240 -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

This command generates a 320×240 sized JPG thumbnail at the 4th second in the video. Put this in a script that changes the time and file name and you're done.

More info: [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Comment: This seems to do what I want, but with one problem. It will process the file from the start on each iteration, getting exponentially slow.

Comment: @Liam - Does it help if you leave the offset time alone (set it at 1) and use the `-ss position` flag to seek further into the file instead? `-ss Seek to given time position in seconds. hh:mm:ss[.xxx] syntax is also supported`

Comment: @liam: put the `-ss` before the `-i` so that the seek happens before the input video gets decoded.  this should speed it up.  [source](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2010-January/023806.html)

Comment: There's a better, *much* faster way to do it with ffmpeg. See my answer below.

Comment: stib's solution is the best IMO.

Answer (score 9):

If you are after a kind of **contact sheet** and if you are working with a Unix-like OS, you can use this elaborate script, called to the point [**Video Contact Sheet *NIX**, short **vcs**](http://p.outlyer.net/vcs).

In the background it also uses `ffmpeg` (by default) or `mplayer`, hence can handle a lot of video formats. It automates the process of capturing still images from the movie and compose these to an image with some header and footer. You can choose e.g. how many captures you want or alternatively the time differences between them.

For a interval of 10 minutes, the invocation is like that:

```
vcs -i 10m input.avi
```

Check the [full list of commandline options](http://p.outlyer.net/dox/vcs:cli_options) for some other tweaks.

Here is an example contact sheet, [taken from the homepage](http://p.outlyer.net/dox/_media/vcs:samples:bbb_excfgs_5x4_160px_default.jpg):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With VLC 1.1.0 and above, you can use the scene video filter:

```
vlc C:\video\to\process.mp4 --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --start-time=10 --stop-time=11 --scene-format=png --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=snap --scene-path=C:\path\for\snapshots\ vlc://quit
```

The above saves 1 out of every 24 frames (--scene-ratio=24), starting at 00:00:10 and ending at 00:00:11.

Just tested and confirmed this works with VLC 2.0.3 on a fresh Windows 8 installation (I have no additional video plugins or software).

Full documentation: http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_create_thumbnails

Answer (score 2):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) can do this for you

`File` -> `Export` -> `Image sequence`

[image]

Comment: Will this save every frame as an image?

Comment: yes, every frame.

Comment: I need to skip most frames, outputting all frames will use up too much storage space. I need just one frame every few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this

> from the VLC command line...
>
> vlc "C:\YOUR\file\path\file.avi" -V
>   image --image-out-prefix=capname
>   --image-out-ratio=60
>
> file.avi is the video you want to
>   capture from, capname is the prefix of
>   the saved images, you might want to
>   play around with the ratio (60 means
>   that 1 out of 60 images is captured)
>   You can add more commands, for example
>   --image-out-format jpeg will save your caps as jpegs instead of of pngs,
>   --snapshot-path lets you choose where to save your caps.

<sub>[Source of above](http://ask.metafilter.com/90735/Automatic-Screenshots-from-a-DVD)</sub>

Comment: I got this message: The command line options couldn't be loaded, check that they are valid.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I got this message: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `--image-out-prefix=capname'

Answer (score 1):

You can skip frames in VirtualDub. Just use "Decimate By" option located at Video -> Frame Rate menu.
For example if you set "Decimate By 100" then use File -> Export -> Image sequence, it will save only every 100th frame.