# Improve quality of ffmpeg created jpgs

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to take a mjpeg feed from an IP camera and convert it into a series of still jpeg images.  Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i http://xxx:xxx@xx.xx.xx.xx/vid.mjpg -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg %05d.jpg
```

Does anyone know a way to specify the level of jpg compression when using ffmpeg to create stills?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's what ended up doing the trick for me:

```
ffmpeg -i http://xx.xx/mjpg/video.mjpg -q:v 1 %05d.jpg
```

The `-q:v 1` was the ticket. It sets the quality of the video encoder, where the `-q` means quality and the `:v` means video. Values range from 1 to 31, where lower means better.

Comment: I don't know if this was available years ago but if you want the source JPEG images unmodified from MJPEG, the answer is here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#mjpeg2jpeg ---- In short: `-c:v copy -bsf:v mjpeg2jpeg` instead of `q:v 1`.

Comment: Does anyone know what default value it uses?

Comment: @JayR.Wren I did some tests and in my case it seems to start out low (good) and after a few seconds rises to 24.8 (bad). I don't know why. ffmpegs shows the current quality as `q`. Here it is *24.8* for example `frame=   64 fps=5.0 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:16.00 bitrate=N/A dup=10 drop=299 speed=1.25x`

Comment: The default value is variable. It starts at 7, but quickly moves towards 1 or 31, based on a few other settings. My build of ffmpeg has a default output avg bitrate of 200000 (wow), so it quickly moves down to q:v 1 (opposite to @JayR.Wren). If you instead specify `-b:v 10000` (avg bitrate target 10k) you'd see it quickly move up towards q:v 31. That said, 7 seems to be the starting point of the variable rate, and to me also seems like a sane default, before tweaking up or down from there (I personally find myself using values from 3 to 9).

Answer (score 6):

`$ ffmpeg -r 1/4 -i %03d.jpg -b 5000 -vcodec mjpeg -qscale 1 5000.avi`

OR

`$ ffmpeg -r 1/4 -i %03d.jpg -vcodec copy -qscale 1 copy.avi`

Reference:

```
r       delay between next jpg, results 4 second
b       bitrate
vcodec  use jpeg encode
qscale  quality ratio
```

Comment: does qscale "compete" with the bitrate specifier, I wonder?

Comment: Isn't this opposite of what is being asked?  This looks like jpeg to mjpeg.  mjpeg to jpeg is the ask.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to export into PPM and use some other tool to convert into JPEG.

I looked into ffmpeg/libavcodec/mjpeg.c. I believe the quality is set to a fixed value.

Also you seem to convert a MJPEG video into JPEG still frames. I think in this case the code in ffmpeg/libavcodec/mjpeg2jpeg_bsf.c runs and the data isn't recoded. So the image quality wouldn't improve anyway.

This is the quantization table definition, I didn't see any reference to *val_?c where the values were scaled before use.

```
/* Set up the standard Huffman tables (cf. JPEG standard section K.3) */
/* IMPORTANT: these are only valid for 8-bit data precision! */
const uint8_t ff_mjpeg_bits_dc_luminance[17] =
{ /* 0-base */ 0, 0, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
const uint8_t ff_mjpeg_val_dc[12] =
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

const uint8_t ff_mjpeg_bits_dc_chrominance[17] =
{ /* 0-base */ 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

const uint8_t ff_mjpeg_bits_ac_luminance[17] =
{ /* 0-base */ 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0x7d };
const uint8_t ff_mjpeg_val_ac_luminance[] =
{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04, 0x11, 0x05, 0x12,
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with PPM, what is that?

Comment: Also, the images look better when I access the camera from the browser compared to the jpgs I'm creating.  That's why I was thinking some compression was occurring.

Comment: PPM is simplest color image format one can imagine. Its just a header like "P6 640 480 255\n" and then the raw data. I just looked. Maybe it actually can't output this format. The only other option then would be -vc rawvideo. Did you try -quality?

Comment: `-vcodec ppm` is needed to export ppm

Answer (score 2):

## Simpliest way I found

Explode video file in `.png` (lossless) then convert them in jpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi image-%07d.png
```

(without option, this will extract all frames.)

I prefer using png compression even if `ffmpeg` is able to produce `.ppm` files (not compressed). Because using PPM will require a lot of disk space and won't be quicker (due to disk write time, of course not tested with SSD;).

Then (using netpbm tools)

```
JPEGQUALITY=95
for file in *.png;do
    echo -n $file...
    pngtopnm $file | pnmtojpeg -q $JPEGQUALITY >${file%.png}.jpg
    echo -e \\e[6Djpg\\e[K.
done
```

Answer (score 0):

## note down the number of a specific frame

```
mpv --osd-msg1='${estimated-frame-number} / ${estimated-frame-count}' vid1.mp4
```

## Save frame numbers in a file one below other eg. frm.txt then run:

```
sed -i 's/^/eq(n\\,/' frm.txt; sed -i 's/$/)\+/'  frm.txt; sed -i '$ s/.$//' frm.txt;        #adds eq(n\, #adds )+ at the end of each line #remove + in lastline (last digit)
```

then extract them as bmp or png

```
frms=$(cat frm.txt); ffmpeg -i vid_1.mp4  -vf "select='$frms'" -fps_mode drop "frames_%03d.bmp"
```

then convert to jpg - the difference is HUGE 350kb (ffmpeg jpg of best quality vs 2MB (bmp converting to jpg)!!!!

```
for pic in *.bmp; do convert  -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 -quality 100  "$pic" "${pic//}_j.jpg"; done
```