# Will 4k video look better than 1080p video on 1080p TV/monitor?

Tags: display, resolution

Topic

Just wondering about this? If I play a 4k video on 1080p monitor/TV, will it look better than playing 1080p video on the same monitor/TV?

Comment: Yeah, the other question is a duplicate of another question here http://superuser.com/questions/819514/what-are-the-differences-of-watching-a-1080p-and-a-720p-version-of-the-same-medi . I'd also add 4k media is *rare*, and outside of netflix there seem very few legitimate sources of it.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends, 4k will be downconverted to 1080p, so it depends on the quality of the originals and also the downconversion process, which takes place inside the monitor/TV - if your tv/monitor has this feature, otherwise by the computer you're displaying on the tv/monitor. So the downconversion can depend on which video player you're using, with different results. It can also depend on the type of images being shown, the downconversion could give better results for certain types and worse for other types. So unless you narrow it down to a specific brand of TV/monitor, a specific piece of video shot in both 4k and 1080p and a specific video player you're using to downconvert, it's not possible to give a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

Due to additional processing the monitor/software has to do to display the video the results may be worse than if you play native 1080p video. In most cases it is better to play 1080p files since they will run natively on your monitor, but probably the difference will not be big.

Another aspect is that if you play 4k you are wasting resources such as hdd space or processing power and you will almost certainly have no benefit in image quality and you may even see a lower quality image.