# How to export thumbnail images with ffmpeg using timestamps in filename

Tags: ffmpeg

This answer to the question
[How to extract one frame of a video every N seconds to an image?](https://superuser.com/questions/135117/how-to-extract-one-frame-of-a-video-every-n-seconds-to-an-image/729351#729351) also shows how to number the output image filenames with `%0xd`

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile.mp4 -r 1 outputFile_%02d.png
```

I would like to know how I can get a timestamp instead (minutes_seconds offset from beginning), for example, the frame @ 5 min 23 sec 98 ms should be written to the file
`outputFile_05_23_98.png`

Comment: Not possible, but you can output (milli)seconds. See [ffmpeg output images filename with time position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50100263/) and the `-frame_pts` option in the [image muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2). You may have to adjust the `round` option for the [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps).